# How to count C++ array items with a template function while allowing for empty arrays

Tags: c++, templates

I use the following template function to count array items:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T, size_t N> constexpr
size_t countof(T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct {} arrayN[] = {{}, {}, {}};
    printf("%zu\n", countof(arrayN));
    return 0;
}
```

It works, but not with an empty array:

```
struct {} array0[] = {};
printf("%zu\n", countof(array0));
```

gcc 5.4 output:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘countof(main()::<anonymous struct> [0])’
note: candidate: template<class T, long unsigned int N> constexpr size_t countof(T (&)[N])
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

If I try to add a specialization:

```
template<typename T> constexpr
size_t countof(T(&)[0])
{
    return 0;
}
```

it even gets weirder:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘countof(main()::<anonymous struct> [0])’
note: candidate: template<class T, long unsigned int N> constexpr size_t countof(T (&)[N])
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note: candidate: template<class T> constexpr size_t countof(T (&)[0])
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   template argument ‘-1’ does not match ‘#‘integer_cst’ not supported by dump_decl#<declaration error>’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to [this array declaration reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) the size expression must evaluate "to a value greater than zero". In short, zero-sized arrays are not valid.

Comment: Talk about bad compiler error messages!

Comment: You could use `std::array` instead.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: in this case, there is no "size expression" in the declaration. But yes, the problem is that there is no such thing as an empty C++ array (see my answer below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to section 8.5.1 of the 2011 standard, "An empty initializer list {} shall not be used as the initializer-clause for an array of unknown bound", with the note: "The syntax provides for empty initializer-lists, but nonetheless C ++ does not have zero length arrays".

Now I wonder why the declaration gets compiled...

Comment: Allowed in GNU C, for a variable length object. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: @jeffrycopps: looks like I tripped over a GNU extension... What is funny is that with a C macro like "#define countof(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof((array)[0]))", everything compiles and the macro gives correct results...